# How to add error trace to response when app crashes

Tags: python, flask

When my app crashes, the client receives a response with:

- `response.status_code = 500`
- `response.text =`

> 500
>   Internal Server Error
>
> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The
>   server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your
>   request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the
>   application.

I would like to also show the error trace, to inform the client about what has gone wrong. How can I do that?

Comment: Well that is what they see, what do you see? Do you get an exception?

Comment: You can enable debug mode to get stack trace. [export FLASK_ENV=development](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) or set up [error handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/#application-errors)

Comment: @dfundako I do get an exception, but I want users to be able to tell me more than "internal server error"

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil is for production and I want users to be able to tell me more than "internal server error"

Comment: [Custom error handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/#application-errors) then?